# Using Webview and Httpclient to check if user is loggedin

Tags: java, php, android

I need to see if user is logged in to my `webview` website and for that i need to run a script that see the value of user(0 if not logged in). `url/checklogin.php` is the script. the `webview` works fine but i am unable to get the value from php to android. `httpclient` always returns 0 even when i log in using `webview`.

here's the `php` script

```
<?php    
  include 'wp-load.php';
  global $current_user;
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $id=$current_user->ID;
  echo $id;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `WebViewClient`, override `onReceivedError`, `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished`. You must be have `accessToken` or `authToken` to confirm if user is authenticated. Based on it you can perform your next action.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to check login in android app, then you need to validate this on your app side. If you are using Auth login, then you need to store access token on your app side so that in the next time you can validate it.